# What happened to the official website for the World Chess Championship 2010?

Tags: world-championship, anand, websites, topalov

The official website for the WCC2010 is supposed to be (and previously was) located at (**please do not visit the page until you read the whole post**): `http://www.anand-topalov.com/`.

Now, unless I am very mistaken, the persons appearing on the above web address at this particular moment, do not look much like Anand or Topalov (protagonists of the WCC 2010). Nor does the content look to be related to chess (well, at least not to how I see chess).

I do not understand the language or the script, but from the pictures it seems that the new main topic of the site is breast enlargement. This leads me to believe that the site has been hacked.

Does anybody know where to report this sort of thing? Is there another copy of the website, on some other location?

Comment: Some information on the WCC 2010 can be found at [FIDE site](http://www.fide.com/component/content/article/1-fide-news/4478-fide-world-chess-championship-match.html) or [Chessdom.com](http://players.chessdom.com/viswanathan-anand/anand-world-chess-champion-2010), but no trace of the official site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, FIDE didn't renew the site, so somebody purchased it. You can check the old contents at http://web.archive.org/web/20100701000000*/http://www.anand-topalov.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The official website for the WCC 2008 seems to have suffered the same fate.